# How can I interrogate the NHibernate class mappings to find out what entities could refer to another entity?

Tags: nhibernate

Best asked with example. Suppose I have these mappings:

```
public class A
{
    internal int Id { get; private set; }

    public X X { get; set; }

    internal class Map : ClassMap<A>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            References(x => x.X);
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    internal int Id { get; private set; }

    private IList<X> XList;

    internal class Map : ClassMap<B>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            HasMany(x => x.XList)
               .Access.Field();

        }
    }
}


public class X
{
    protected internal virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    internal class Map : ClassMap<X>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for code that would accept a NHibernate (or FluentNHibernate) Configuration (or FluentConfiguration) object and output something like:

```
A - property member X
B - field member XList
```

Obviously there's a lot I haven't considered like subclass mappings, ternary relationships, component mappings etc, but what I'm looking for is a list for all the places where one entity, when stored in the database, may reference another entity.

I've tried to look in the Configuration.ClassMappings class, but the NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass is quite a monster and I got lost fairly quickly. Does anybody have any pointers on how to do this (preferably without having to become agonizingly familiar with the NHibernate mappings code :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK using the configuration is the way to go here.

```
var propertiesWithX = config.ClassMappings
    .SelectMany(clazz => clazz.PropertyClosureIterator)
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(X) || IsCollectionOfTypeX(prop));
```